# bash: How to use multiple string manipulations (parameter expansion) in one step?

Tags: bash

I have `string=substr1-substr2-substr3.substr4` where the substrings are of variable length. I want to extract `substr3` from `string` and am thinking of doing it using the `${string##pattern}` and `${string%pattern}` string manipulation expansions. Using this approach, it's clear I need to run `${string##*-}` and run `${string%.*}` on the resulting expansion, or vice versa. My questions are:

1. is this the best choice?
2. If yes, how do i run both in a single step? When I try to do something like `${string##*-${string%.*}}` or `${string%.*${string##*-}}` I just get back the full string. I realize i could always do the extraction in two steps by assigning an intermediate variable to the result of the first step, and then manipulating that; but I want to do it in one step. How do I go about it?

TIA!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
string=substr1-substr2-substr3.substr4
```

`${string%.*}` is

```
substr1-substr2-substr3
```

so, `${string##*-${string%.*}}` is

```
${string##*-substr1-substr2-substr3}
```

which means to remove from the start of `string`, everything up to and including `-substr1-substr2-substr3`. But there's no such substring in `string`, as there's no dash in front of `substr1`, so you get the original string.

What you probably want is

```
string=substr1-substr2-substr3.substr4
result="${string%.*}"
result="${result##*-}"
```

which leads to `result` containg `substr3`.

In Zsh, you could do it in one step: `result=${${string%.*}##*-}`, but that doesn't work in Bash.

In Bash, you're limited to using expansions on the right side of `#` or `%`, and that doesn't help you here since you need to remove parts from both the start and end of the string.

---

Alternatively, if `$string` doesn't contain newline characters, you can use

```
IFS=.- read -r a b c d <<< "$string"
```

and read `substr3` off from `c`.

In that case, depending on the shell and the size of the string, the contents of `$string` will be either stored in a temporary file or fed through a pipe which `read` will read the first line from and split it according to `$IFS`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation; makes sense. I did want to avoid the multiple step extraction... had thought of the `read` + `here string` solution, but wanted to see if i could do it with parameter expansion instead. But, yeah I think I am going to go with the alternative. Any particular reason I might need the `-r` flag though?

Comment: @computronium, `-r` tells `read` not to treat backslashes specially, otherwise they can be used to make the delimiters, well, not delimit. `IFS=.- read a b <<< "foo\-bar"` puts `foo-bar` in `a` and nothing in `b`.

Comment: got that, but in my case the here string will not have any backslashes. so was wondering if there was any other reason you might have suggested it... thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @computronium, well, force of habit, and of course I couldn't be sure what you'd have there.

Answer (score -2):

The question was about bash but for anyone who is on Zsh and comes across this question through search... this might be helpful.

## An answer for Zsh only...

... and maybe other shells but not bash (5.1.16)

To do multiple string substitutions on Zsh you can nest [parameter expansions](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn):

```
string=substr1-substr2-substr3.substr4
result=${${string##*-}%.*}
```

Comment: Please explain the down-vote.